# IDispatch object that responds to all properties?

Tags: object, idispatch

I want to create an IDispatch object that returns a value for every property.  Ask it for "foo", it returns something.  "bar" returns something.  "faid1jhgi31jifj" as well.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `GetIDsForNames` methods with an appropriate implementation that returns a valid `DISPID` for any input parameters. Then override the `Invoke` method to ensure to return the correct value based on the dispatch id.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the IDispatch::GetTypeInfo and ::GetTypeInfoCount functions?  Don't I have to return a valid ITypeInfo there?

Comment: Never mind.  I see that GetTypeInfoCount can optionally just return 0.

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at IDispatchEx, which is designed to give more flexibility for dynamic interfaces.